# how to prove that ()=1+−(1+^(1+))^(1/(1+)) is approximated by 1-e^(-)^(-)

Tags: limits, approximation

This for >0 and large x>0. Series expansions don't seem to lead anywhere, so there must be an alternative approach as the convergence is really rapid as x increases. I found this relationship empirically, but would like to prove it deductively. The reason for seeking this is that the RHS provides a manageable inverse function.

Many thanks

Comment: By approximation do you mean the difference of the two functions tends to zero as $ x $ tends to infinity?

Comment: The expansion near $x=+\infty$ is $f(x)=1-\frac1{1+\alpha}x^{-\alpha}+O(x^{-(1+2\alpha)})$ which doesn't agree with $1-e^{-\alpha}x^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: I mean that the difference/ratio tends quickly to unity. I will look at this approximation - for which many thanks. How do I prove it?